# Makefile ignores pattern rule with subdirectory in pattern

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following directory structure:

```
.
  bar/
    foo/
      test.ext1
  _foo/
```

I wrote a makefile with the following rule:

```
_%.ext2: bar/%.ext1 # % should match foo/test
    echo $*
```

however running `make _foo/test.ext2` gives:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '_foo/test.ext2'.  Stop.
```

When I looked at `make -d _foo/test.ext2`, it doesn't even consider the above rule, i.e. it jumps straight to trying built-in rules. I don't understand what's happening here, so can someone explain it to me?

EDIT:
I want to be able to generate from arbitrary files in `bar`, e.g.:

- `bar/foo/test-2.ext1` -> `_foo/test-2.ext2`
- `bar/baz/another.ext1` -> `_baz/another.ext2`
- etc.

The existence of `_foo` and `_baz` is guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match):

> When the target pattern does not contain a slash (and it usually does not), directory names in the file names are removed from the file name before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix.

and

> When prerequisites are turned into file names, the directories from the stem are added at the front, while the rest of the stem is substituted for the `%`

Therefore with a pattern like `_%.ext2` the underscore is matched against a file name, not a directory name. So it does not match `_foo/test.ext2` but it would match `foo/_test.ext2` (and look for `foo/bar/test.ext1`). See for yourself:

```
$ cat Makefile
_%.ext2: bar/%.ext1
        echo Making $@ from $<

$ make -dr _foo/test.ext2
...
Considering target file '_foo/test.ext2'.
 File '_foo/test.ext2' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for '_foo/test.ext2'.
 No implicit rule found for '_foo/test.ext2'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file '_foo/test.ext2'.
Must remake target '_foo/test.ext2'.
make: *** No rule to make target '_foo/test.ext2'.  Stop.

$ make -dr foo/_test.ext2
...
Considering target file 'foo/_test.ext2'.
 File 'foo/_test.ext2' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'foo/_test.ext2'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem 'test'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite 'foo/bar/test.ext1'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem 'test'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite 'foo/bar/test.ext1'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'foo/bar/test.ext1'.
  Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 No implicit rule found for 'foo/_test.ext2'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'foo/_test.ext2'.
Must remake target 'foo/_test.ext2'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo/_test.ext2'.  Stop.
```

The easiest way to fix it is to make target include slash. If you can move outputs elsewhere, you can do i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
OBJDIR := obj
$(OBJDIR)/_%.ext2: bar/%.ext1
        echo Making $@ from $<

$ make obj/_foo/test.ext2
echo Making obj/_foo/test.ext2 from bar/foo/test.ext1
Making obj/_foo/test.ext2 from bar/foo/test.ext1
```

or even

```
$ cat Makefile
_/%.ext2: bar/%.ext1
        echo Making $@ from $<

$ make _/foo/test.ext2
echo Making _/foo/test.ext2 from bar/foo/test.ext1
Making _/foo/test.ext2 from bar/foo/test.ext1
```

If you cannot do that, you can try to reference through full path, i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
$(CURDIR)/_%.ext2: bar/%.ext1
        echo Making $@ from $<

$ make $(pwd)/_foo/test.ext2
echo Making /path/to/curdir/_foo/test.ext2 from bar/foo/test.ext1
Making /path/to/curdir/_foo/test.ext2 from bar/foo/test.ext1
```

Note that using `./` does not work since GNU make strips leading `./` from targets making pattern not match again:

```
$ cat Makefile
./_%.ext2: bar/%.ext1
        echo Making $@ from $<

$ make -dr ./_foo/test.ext2
...
Considering target file '_foo/test.ext2'.
 File '_foo/test.ext2' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for '_foo/test.ext2'.
 No implicit rule found for '_foo/test.ext2'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file '_foo/test.ext2'.
Must remake target '_foo/test.ext2'.
make: *** No rule to make target '_foo/test.ext2'.  Stop.
```

If you wish to make your peer review colleagues nervous, you can also use some second expansion magic to generate proper prerequisite names, e.g.:

```
$ cat Makefile
percent := %
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.ext2: bar/$$(patsubst _$$(percent),$$(percent),$$(@D))/$$*.ext1
        echo Making $@ from $<

$ make _foo/test.ext2
echo Making _foo/test.ext2 from bar/foo/test.ext1
Making _foo/test.ext2 from bar/foo/test.ext1
```

Note: `%` must be quoted through `$(percent)` variable, otherwise GNU make parser may complain or misinterpret the `patsubst` function.

Your final approach works, because your final solution is a static pattern rule. It does not apply the same 'strip directory' approach, rather it just matches the strings.

Comment: Thank you for the rigorous explanation! I did read the manual, but I guess I didn't understand correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The rule `_%.ext2: bar/%.ext1`, when invoked on the target `_foo/test.ext2` will match the rule with the stem (%) equal to `foo`. For the rule to work, there need to be a file (or a rule) to create bar/%.ext1 = `bar/foo.ext1`.

According to the OP, the input file is bar/foo/test1.ext1.

Try adjusting the dependency:

```
_%/test.ext2: bar/%/test.ext1
    echo $*
```

Comment: That solves the problem, but sacrifices generality, i.e. I want the rule to apply to all any file that satisfies that type of match.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which case is not covered by the rule ? Might be a good idea to enumerate requirement in the question.

Comment: Say for example that there was another directory, `bar/baz/another_file.ext1`. I want to be able to generate `_baz/another_file.ext2` (assuming `_baz` exists of course).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

I managed to avoid this problem by adding the following to the makefile:

```
TARGETS := $(patsubst bar/%,_%,$(patsubst %.ext1,%.ext2,$(wildcard bar/**/*.ext1)))

$(TARGETS): _%.ext2: bar/%.ext1 # % should match foo/test
    echo $*
```

What this does is basically construct the targets beforehand (from the files available in `bar/`) and then apply the rule to them. I am, however not sure why the pattern rule applies in this case and not in the original one, so I would still appreciate an explanation.